# passing as parameter an object derived from a class in C#

Tags: c#, java, class, inheritance

As you all know using java it is possible to create methods which require one or more objects extended from another class; to do this you have to write:

```
public void method(Class<? extends class_name> Object_name)
```

I was wondering whether there is a corresponding statement in C#. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's accepting a *type* rather than an *object*, but you can do something slightly similar with generic methods in C#:

```
public void Foo<T>() where T : MyClass
```

Then you can use `typeof(T)` within the method.

If you need to specify an actual *object* compatible with type `T`, you can have that as a normal method parameter of type `T`.

If you need more, please update your question with more specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

you can make your method signature Generic and use a constraint

eg:

```
public static ObjectB GetObjectBFromInterface<T>(T item) where T : IObject
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d5x73970%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for more information on Generic Type Constraints

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generic method and use a [type parameter constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public void Method<T>(T obj) where T : YourBaseClass
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't coded in Java in years, so I'm not familiar with the `<? extends` construct, however, I think you are asking how to pass in an interface or abstract class to a method.

You could use generics, but I think you would be better off just using the base class

```
public void Method(BaseClass baseClassParamName) 
{
   baseClassParamName.HasAccessToMethodsDefinedInTheBase();
}
```